# Why does make not print the message of $(info ...)?

Tags: makefile

I have this simple `Makefile`:

```
$(info i)
$(warning w)

all:
    echo xyz
```

When I run it, it prints

```
Makefile:2: w
echo xyz
xyz
```

I have expected the `$(info i)` instruction to print `i`. What do I have to change so that the `i` is also printed?

Comment: Can't reproduce, prints `i` for me. (GNU Make 4.2.1 on Windows.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always specify the version of the software you're using.

The `$(warning ...)` function was added to GNU make 3.78 (released in 1999).  The `$(info ...)` function was added to GNU make 3.81 (released in 2006).

Perhaps your version of GNU make is between those two releases.

Comment: This was exactly it. I didn't realize my make was *that* old.